# Discuss about java.lang.IllegalStateException:onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I call code below after screen rotation

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, mPdfFragment).commit();
```

But I get the below error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.microsoft.pdfviewertestapplication, PID: 18799
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1415)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1433)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:687)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:663)
    at com.microsoft.pdfviewertestapplication.MainActivity.documentOpenedSuccessfully(MainActivity.java:263)
    at com.microsoft.pdfviewertestapplication.MainActivity.onDocumentOpened(MainActivity.java:548)
    at com.microsoft.pdfviewer.PdfFragment.onPdfFragmentPasswordDialogDocumentOpened(PdfFragment.java:2271)
    at com.microsoft.pdfviewer.PdfFragmentPasswordDialog.verifyAfterEnterPress(PdfFragmentPasswordDialog.java:311)
    at com.microsoft.pdfviewer.PdfFragmentPasswordDialog.access$600(PdfFragmentPasswordDialog.java:38)
    at com.microsoft.pdfviewer.PdfFragmentPasswordDialog$5.onEditorAction(PdfFragmentPasswordDialog.java:339)
```

I checked with the source code of `FragmentManager.java`:

```
if (mStateSaved) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(
       "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState");
}
```

I find that it matters with the boolean value `mStateSaved`. I find that in `onSaveInstanceState` function it is set to true. But if I bring fragment background and forward, it also calls `mStateSaved`, so I am confused. How can I set the boolean value from my code?

PS: I need to call commit after onResume. And if I bring my fragment background and forward, it will work well, it also call commit after onPause and onSaveInstance, so I am confused.

Comment: Read this [link](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)

Comment: I find that the last override function is onPostResume, and it set mStateSaved as false.